# Insert data metodo POST symfony3

Tags: php, mysql, symfony3

Estoy haciendo una app con symfony3, tengo los metodos CRUD en el controlador, pero no logro insertar datos en el DB, por ahora solo estoy haciendo el backend y probando con Postman. Este es el metodo que inserta:

```
/**
     * @Route("/event/new", name="new_event")
     * @method({"POST"})
     */
    public function newEvent(Request $request){

        $event = new Evento();
        $descripcion = $request->request->get('descripcion');
        $obs = $request->request->get('obs');
        $inicio = $request->request->get('inicio');
        $fin = $request->request->get('fin');

        $event->setDescripcion($descripcion);
        $event->setObs($obs);
        $event->setInicio(new \ DateTime ($inicio));
        $event->setFin(new \DateTime($fin));

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($event);
        $em->flush();

        return  new Response("Folio: ". $event->getId());
    }
```

Es como si no recibiera los parametros porque me sale este error:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO evento (descripcion, obs, inicio, fin) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [null, null, "2018-04-09 22:20:03", "2018-04-09 22:20:03"]:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'descripcion' cannot be null
```

alguna idea de como solucionar esto?
gracias

Comment: Comenta tu codigo dentro de tu **action** y devuelve esto: return  new Response("request: ". print_r($request->request->all(), true)); y comprueba que el arreglo devuelto sea lo que estas pasando en el POST

Comment: eso me devuelve: request: Array ( )

Comment: si te devuelve un array vacío es que no le esta llegando nada desde el POST